# Вывод множества точек (более 200) на яндекс карту, версия API 2.1, бесплатный ключ

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Как правильно вывести множество точек (более 200) на яндекс карту?
сейчас делаю так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let = currentCoords = null;
ymaps.ready(function () {
    
    placemark_0 = new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lon], {
        hintContent: "",
        balloonContent: "текст 1"
    }),
    placemark_1 = new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lon], {
        hintContent: "",
    balloonContent: "текст 2"}),
    
    ...
    
    placemark_n = new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lon], {
        hintContent: "",
        balloonContent: "Текст n"
    });
    
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [lat, lon],
        zoom: 5,
        controls: [],
    });
    
    myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark_0).add(placemark_1).add(placemark_n);
    
</script>
```

Мой вариант не работает когда точек становится больше 170. Версия API 2.1, использую бесплатный ключ.